# JSON Unexpected token s

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, visual-studio-cordova

`JSON.parse()` seems not to work with my code, I'm not sure what's causing it.

JS Code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(obj.status + " " + obj.type);
if (obj.status == "success") {
   document.cookie = "accounttype=" + obj.type;
   document.cookie = "name=" + obj.name;
   var accounttype = getCookie(accounttype);
   if (accounttype == "Seller") {
      window.location.href = "../html/sell.html";
   }
}
```

PHP Code:

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1){
        echo '{"status": "success", "type":"$account", "name":"$name"}';
    }else{
        echo '{"status": "failed"}';
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me, thanks!

**EDIT UPDATED CODE**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);
        console.log(obj.status + " " + obj.type);
        if (obj.status == "success") {
            document.cookie = "accounttype=" + obj.type;
            document.cookie = "name=" + obj.name;
            var accounttype = getCookie(accounttype);
            if (accounttype == "Seller") {
                window.location.href = "../html/sell.html";
            }
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Invalid username or password!", "error");
            document.getElementById("password").value = "";
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "../php/login.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
```

And here's the updated PHP code:

```
<?php
    include("checkdbconnection.php");

        session_start();


    $username = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password);

    $getLogin = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $getLogin);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $name = $row["firstname"];
    $account = $row["account_type"];

    if(!$result){
       echo "Query Error: ". mysqli_error($conn);
       die();
    }

    $jsonsuccess = ["status": "success", "type": $account, "name": $name];
    $jsonfail = ["status": "failed"];
    $jsonsuccstring = json_encode($jsonsuccess);
    $jsonfailstring = json_encode($jsonfail)
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1){
        echo $jsonsuccstring;
    }else{
        echo $jsonfailstring;
    }
?>
```

Console returns undefined for both JSON returned values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()`

Your server side response should be

```
 $json = ["status": "success", "type": $account, "name": $name];

 $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
 echo $jsonstring;
 die();
```

Your JS code should be like

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "URL.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        // Here is the tip
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        //Here is success 
        alert(data.status);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

You should verify your json string. If it is ok try this:

```
var jsonStr="your json string";
var json=JSON.stringify(jsonStr);
json=JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: Didn't work however, the error changed to Exception: Unexpected token <. Any clue what that means?

Comment: JS: http://i.imgur.com/cweEY6A.png

PHP: http://i.imgur.com/rLKqdrS.png

Comment: What you're getting on `console.log(this.responseText)` ?

Comment: before it was undefined, but now it triggers the error even before it prints something.

Comment: what's the error man ? can you updated the full code jsfiddle in your question ?

Comment: @IvanRalphG.Vitto If it's not working check and verify your JSON string, see I've updated my answer and show you a way what needs to be done to take care about the json.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, let me try the edits you made.

Comment: Show me full code or jsfiddle with yout server side and ajax call and response you're getting in your network tab in your ajax ?

Comment: Check the question

Comment: You're nothing getting in `this.responseText` ?

Comment: Did you set `http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); ?`

Comment: I don't have that in any of my code, is it suppose to be in my PHP file?

Comment: No man,  
You're nothing getting in `this.responseText`? Can you console and see what you're getting any errors or response in ?

Comment: I'm getting undefined if I'm trying to call the JSON values.

Comment: Just try to pass a static response from server and see what your getting on JS code,

Comment: I tried passing a static value then it returned unexpected token error

Comment: Exception: unexpected token '

Comment: Nothing looks problem in your code, I would still suggest to use the code as an example what I've shown you and If you can provide jsfiddle that will help me to understand the exact problem